# Как обновить базу данных Постгрес для 1с?

Tags: postgresql, 1с

Как правильно обновить Postgresql 9.6 на 14. При переносе базы через SQL возникает ошибка при запуске клиента:

```
2023-12-13 23:01:09.787 UTC [18208] ERROR:  CREATE EXTENSION ... FROM is no longer supported at character 52
2023-12-13 23:01:09.787 UTC [18208] STATEMENT:  create extension if not exists mchar schema public FROM unpackaged
```

Выгружать базу средствами 1с и загружать в новую базу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновлял Posgresql 9.6 на 13.4, средствами 1С, размер маленький 7ГБ, самый простой и понятный способ, я по отзывам, понял что если база большая, то процесс может значительно затянуться и может вылетать в процессе.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я вижу, вы взяли PostgreSQL 14 версии без поддержки патчей от 1C. Вам нужно найти версию с патчами от 1C. Также вы ничего не сказали насчёт того, какую ОС вы используете.

Здесь сможете получить сборку от Postgres Pro, совместимую с 1С: https://1c.postgres.ru

На портале ИТС 1С сможете получить сборку, совместимую с 1С, если у вас есть туда доступ.

Comment: С поддержкой. С "нуля" база создается

Comment: что ж, видать, дело в синтаксисе дампа. поищите, нет ли в нём конструкции из сообщения об ошибке.
в версии 9.6 указанный в сообщении об ошибке синтаксис был допустим: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-createextension?lang=ru
в версии 14 уже нет: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/sql-createextension

Comment: Ага, возмножно, но не перебирать же дамп вручную.

Comment: Скорее всего в таблицах 1с есть запись в которой указан диалект версии базы и клиент выполняет хранимку этой версии.